# How to remove Mac extended attributes files on Windows

Tags: windows, macos

I backed up some files using a Mac and when I copied them back to Windows I ended up with a copy of every single file - `foo` also creates `._foo`. Apparently these are Mac extended attribute files. Very annoying.

How can I safely remove them all on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I found is with Powershell. They all have the same size and are all marked hidden so you can do it quite safely like this:

```
 gci -Recurse -Hidden -Path ._* | ?{$_.Length -eq 4KB} | rm -Force
```

`-Force` is necessary to delete hidden files.

Comment: Works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The answer using gci in powershell didn't work for me but this did:

`del /s /q /f /a ._*`

which I located from here: [Awesome Toast Explanation](https://awesometoast.com/delete-all-instances-of-ds_store-in-windows/)

Hopefully that helps someone.  Also, the '._' files can be deleted at source on the mac: after copying the files from mac to a removable drive and whilst drive is still connected to the mac, drag the folder path into this command in a Mac Terminal window:

```
dot_clean -nm
```

Lots of resources on the web for using dot_clean -nm but sadly I couldn't find the one I used to attribute them.